# Intersection of linear subspaces is $\{ 0 \}$ iff distance between respective unit vectors is positive in finite dimensions

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces

The question is from Linear Operator Theory in Engineering and Science by Arch W. Naylor and George R. Sell, Springer

> Problem 5 from Section 5.10. Let $M$ and $N$ be linear subspaces of a normed linear space $X$ and $\delta(M,N)=\inf\{ \|x-y  \|: x \in M, y \in N, \|x\|=\|y\|=1\}.$ Prove that if $X$ is finite dimensional, then $\delta(M,N)>0$ if and only if $M\bigcap N=\{0\}.$

I know to use that fact that in a finite dim. space, $B=\{x\in X:\|x\|\leq 1\}$ is compact. But I don't see where I can use it.

Comment: What about $Q=\{(x,y)\in X\times X\,:\, \lVert x\rVert=1\land \lVert y\rVert=1\}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S=\{x\in X\mid\|x\|=1\}$. If $M\cap N\neq\{0\}$, take $v\in(M\cap N)\setminus\{0\}$. Then $\frac v{\lVert v\rVert}\in M\cap N$ and therefore $\delta(M,N)=0$.

If $M\cap N=\{0\}$, then $M\cap S$ and $N\cap S$ and disjoint closed subsets of $S$. Since $S$ is compact, $M\cap S$ and $N\cap S$ are compact too. And therefore $\delta(M,N)>0$, since $\delta(M,N)$ is the distance from $M\cap S$ to $N\cap S$, which is positive (since the sets are compact and disjoint).

Comment: if $B = \{x \in X: \|x\| \le 1\}$, then $0 \in (M \cap B) \cap (N \cap B)$, maybe here $B$ is $S = \{x \in X: \|x\| = 1\}$ ?

Comment: @xunitc I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is $D$, maybe it is "and $N\cap S$ and disjoint closed subsets of $X$. Since $S$ is compact". but I understand your proof, it is nice.

Comment: @xunitc Yes, it was a typo! I meant $S$.